# Fourier Series: How is it invented?

Tags: fourier-series

I am currently reading Digital Image Processing by Gonzalez and Woods and in the the chapter of **Filtering in Frequency Domain** there is a huge mention about Fourier Transform.

The author writes,

> " Fourier's Contribution in this field states that any periodic
>   function can be expressed as the sum of sines and /or cosines of
>   different frequencies each multiplied by a different coefficient
>   (which we now call **Fourier Series**)"

Can anyone explain me on a basic mathematical level on how this modelling of every periodic function just with sines and/or cosines is possible?

Comment: Your title asks a history question and your final paragraph asks us to give you a mathematical intro. Which is it you're actually after?

Comment: Concerning the historical part, it would be more appropriate to post that question at our [History of Science and Mathematics site](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/), but actually that question [has already been asked](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7957/what-are-some-good-references-elucidating-the-discovery-creation-of-fourier-seri).

Comment: Here's one viewpoint: The fourier basis functions are the eigenfunctions of the derivative operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ (assuming the derivative operator is defined on an appropriate space of functions). But the integration by parts formula tells us that the adjoint of $\frac{d}{dx}$ is $-\frac{d}{dx}$ (in a setting where the boundary terms vanish). So the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ is skew-symmetric, hence it is normal. By the spectral theorem from linear algebra, we would expect (or at least hope) that the eigenfunctions of $\frac{d}{dx}$ form an orthonormal basis.

Comment: If you're after a quick introduction to what on earth a Fourier transform is, [here](https://youtu.be/spUNpyF58BY) is a nice youtube video by 3blue1brown.